Reactjs embedded iframe giving error of refused to connect while Rendering attachment url
I have build  a django backend to store a file in static , and through api i am fetching file details along with uri in reactjs
i want to show the file in  , but here i am facing issue of "refused to connect"
models.py
class Attachment(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='v1/file/attachment/')    
    size = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True) 
    

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.size and self.file:
            self.size = self.file.size 
            
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

Views.py
def get_folder_data(folder, serializer_class):
    
    data = serializer_class(folder).data
    children = Folder.objects.filter(parent=folder)
    if children.exists():
        data['children'] = []
        for child in children:
            data['children'].append(get_folder_data(child, serializer_class))
    files = File.objects.filter(folder=folder)
    if files.exists():
        data['files'] = FileSerializer(files, many=True).data
    return data

on frontend
const uri = BaseUrl.FileServices.substring(0, BaseUrl.FileServices.indexOf("/v1"))+file.attachment_file_url

 <iframe src={uri} width="800" height="600" title="Embedded File"></iframe>

but i am able to open the link of pdf file on new tab ,
but it is not working in iframe
how can i solve this ?
PS: I want to render pdf . You can suggest ,if there any other way
enter image description here
